# Error in opening Android Studio (latest version) because of jdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, compilation

Earlier I had `jdk 7.` Everything was working well with that. I was able to open `Android Studio` as it was well configured with `jdk 7`. I was able to create `android` project and `gradle` successfully.

But while I clicked the run button to run the app in the `AVD`, it showed me the error that it was unable to compile the program (the program was a simple Hello World display). It said that it required `jdk 8` to compile the program.

So, I installed `jdk 8` and the corresponding runtime and created the environment for the both successfully just like I had done for `jdk 7`. Now the Android Studio is not ready to start.

It shows the error that

> jdk 8 is not a valid JVM.

I have also attached the screenshot of the error, the `java` environment variable on my machine and `Java` control panel showing the installed `Java` Version and runtime version. With `jdk 7`, I was able to compile and run simple `java` program of hello world on command prompt.

Now, using `jdk 8`, the program is getting compiled successfully creating an object file but it is not able to run the program. Even in Control Panel, on opening 'Java', it shows that `Java 8` has been successfully installed, configured and enabled on the system.

I am not able to get the problem. The same problem was being faced with `8u91`. So, I also installed `8u92`. Here are the screenshots I uploaded...

[Android Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hk4f.png)

[Proper Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKHtq.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just specify till the jdk version

Dont include the bin folder

Edit your JAVA_HOME variable like this

```
 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\
```

Comment: Thank-you, that worked. But now, the jdk location is fixed on jdk 7. I opened File --> Project Structure and edited the jdk location to jdk 8 and then clicked on 'Try Again' for 'Gradle Project sync' but again the Gradle Project sync was failed. An error pop out 

                           Invalid Project JDK

Comment: I am writing the problem again after this comment

Comment: Thank-you, that worked. But now, the jdk location is fixed on jdk 7. I opened File --> Project Structure and edited the jdk location to jdk 8 and then clicked on 'Try Again' for 'Gradle Project sync' but again the Gradle Project sync was failed. An error pop out 

                           Invalid Project JDK
                          Please choose a valid directory
(there was this option) --> Open JDK settings 

(I am continuing in the next comment...)

Comment: I clicked on it which redirected me to File --> Project Structure and when I checked the jdk directory, it was automatically changed back to jdk 7 (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17) without any of my intervention. Actually, I have removed jdk 7 far before from my system...

Comment: Change your jdk directory to jdk 8 path and then goto File->Invalidate Caches and Restart then click on Invalidate and Restart

Comment: the problem is not solved. Again the same problem has occur...I tried it twice but there is no change in the situation, not even 0.1%.
please guide...

Comment: please guide me...this problem has been irritating me since a week

Comment: have you checked your jdk path properly , may be your path might be in correct, check version number properly as well

Comment: yeah...I had copied the jdk address from the address bar, so it is obviously correct and the version number is 8u92

Comment: open cmd and type java -version and tell me what it is?

Comment: can you post your app's build.gradle file